# do I need a new field for counting scores form another table?

Tags: postgresql, function, models, objection.js

I have a `Users` Table

it has id, username, `A`, and `B` as my columns.

I also have a `Votes` Table.

a user can vote on `A`, and `B`.

it has id, user_id foreign key, A_id foreign key, and B_id foreign key.

I would like to do a query to Users and have the tally of votes for `A` and votes for `B` included.

so lets say I find a User with the id of 1,

How would I get something like

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "display_name": "test",
        "A" : 32,
        "B" : 132
}
```

Assuming there are 32 rows in the Votes table and 132 rows for B in the Votes table.

Answer (score 0):

simplified table:

```
t=# select* from users;
 i | t
---+---
 1 | A
 1 | B
 1 | B
 2 | A
 2 | A
 2 | B
(6 rows)
```

query:

```
t=# select distinct
i
, sum(case when t='A' then count(1) filter (where t='A') else 0 end) over (partition by i) a
, sum(case when t='B' then count(1) filter (where t='B') else 0 end ) over (partition by i)b
from users
group by i,t
order by i;
 i | a | b
---+---+---
 1 | 1 | 2
 2 | 2 | 1
(2 rows)
```

Comment: thanks, but I cannot change my tables because there is existing relationships as well that I did not provide in this example.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you to... just use the method agaist your table